# Install elasticsearch plugins with ansible

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, ansible

I'm using ansible for elasticsearch ( [ansible-elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/ansible-elasticsearch)) and need to install plugins from a url , local file, or alternative repo. is there a way I can reference a plugin by something other than just:

```
  es_plugins:
    -plugin: elasticsearch/license
     version: latest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source](https://github.com/elastic/ansible-elasticsearch/blob/master/tasks/elasticsearch-plugins.yml#L40) suggests that plugins are installed this way `{{es_home}}/bin/plugin install {{ item.plugin }}`.

And [ES docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/installation.html) explains possible ways to install plugins from alternative locations.

So you should be good to go with:

```
es_plugins:
  - plugin: my_git_id/my_plugin
  - plugin: http://url_to_my_custom_plugin
  - plugin: file:///path/to/plugin.zip
```